# Why javascript function object is used before the expression returned is valid?

Tags: javascript

Why is the javascript code snippet below valid.

1. I cannot figure out why the **require1** variable can be used in the body itself, even before the function expression is return.
2. In what situation, should we add a property to the function object like **require1.cache**, instead of just declaring a function and with **function(){}** and use it in the **require1** function body.

   ```
   const require1 = (name)=> {
       console.log(require1.cache);
   };
   require1.cache = {name:'test'};

   require1('test');
   ```

Answer (score 2):

The function is not *evaluated* immediately - the function first gets *assigned* to the variable name `require1`, and then *later*, once it's called, `require1.cache` will work, because `require1` has been assigned to. If the function was immediately invoked before the assignment, you would be right - an error would be thrown, because `require1` would not have been defined at that point.

Adding properties to *functions* is pretty bad practice, though - better to use outer variables, objects, or use constructors (`new`) and assign to the instantiation. For example:

```js
class require {
  constructor(cache) {
    this.cache = cache;
  }
  log() {
    console.log(this.cache);
  }
}
const require1 = new require({ name: 'test' });
require1.log();
```

Answer (score 0):

This fragment:

```
(name) => {
    console.log(require1.cache);
};
```

is the definition of an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions). It is an anonymous function that can also be written as:

```
function (name) {
    console.log(require1.cache);
};
```

Being anonymous, it needs to either be used immediately in an expression or stored in a variable (otherwise it is lost and you wrote it for nothing). In your example, it is stored in the `require1` variable.

The code of the function is not executed when it is declared but later, when it is called as `require1('test')`.

The function uses the variable `require1` that is not declared inside the function. This means it is a variable from an enclosing scope (a global variable, maybe). Assigning a value to an undeclared variable creates a variable in the global scope. The value of an undeclared variable is [`undefined`]

Read more about JavaScript [variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

When the function is executed (line `require1('test');`) the variable `require1` already exists; it has been initialized on the first line. Also, its `cache` property has already been set.